# Removing excess Decking Oil

Tags: deck, decking, oil

I have oiled my decking for the 1st time yesterday and on checking it today there are patches where I have applied too much and these patches are shiny and sticky. Whats the best approach for removing the patches and reapplying?

Edit: Using Wickes decking oil (image attached).

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please edit your post to describe what type of decking and "oil" we're talking about.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Added a photo of the tin of that helps?

Comment: I see that you're too busy to make your images upright. Could you find the time to tell us what type of decking we're looking at? :)

Comment: Hey apologies I'm trying to use the app for SO which isnt going well! I will sort this post out on the PC tonight.!